# egrep with dynamic output

Tags: dynamic, grep, output

I am trying to egrep rows that contain specific characters.
When I perform single egrep, it works fine

```
egrep -w -h -R 'name' /path/file1.txt > /path/file2.txt
```

But when I perform multiple egrep using for loop, the output were all empty.

```
for i in {Adam Bob Chuck Dan Eli Frank}; do egrep -w -h -R 'i' /path/file1.txt > /path/name"$i".txt; done
```

I double checked the output files by single egrep, there should have some information in each of the output file. I am doing something wrong here but I could not figure out what it is..

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What shell are you using? Bash shouldn't require curly braces around the list, and you would need to use `"$i"` instead of `'i'`.

Comment: I am using Bash. I just tried your suggesting replacing 'i' with "$i", and IT WORKED!! THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's extremely inefficient as you're calling grep and parsing the whole input file once per name (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Just read the input file once:

```
awk -v names='Adam Bob Chuck Dan Eli Frank' '
    BEGIN { split(names,list) }
    {
        for (i in list) {
            if ( $0 ~ ("\\<" list[i] "\\>") ) {
                print > ("/path/name" i ".txt")
            }
        }
    }
' /path/file1.txt
```

The above uses GNU awk for word boundaries (`\<` and `\>`), with other awks you'd just need to change the regexp comparison to: `$0 ~ ("(^|[^[:alnum:]_])" list[i] "([^[:alnum:]_]|$)")`.